# Unity3D Growing Plants Realtime

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, server

I Created Farming Game with Unity3D and C# but i will make game multiplayer + realtime harvesting and growing

My problem is what i need or how to make growing of plants with real time.

like farmville 2 the crops working with real time

Comment: This question may be better suited here :https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks @fruggiero for telling me.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific when asking on a site like that. This question is super open-ended and probably better suited to a forum.

Comment: @tadman i edit my question, you can read it again

Comment: There are a few ways you can do this but for multiplayer you likely will want to setup some sort of authority server to manage time based occurrences. That said you could just rely on the users system time if you don't care about the security side. Personally I have use the unity www class and a php driven web server in the past for such things. In 5.0+ the wwwForm class may also be of use.

Comment: You need water particles, 3D seeds, volumetric sun, and a lot of love !